# Is there a closed form for the summation of a tetration series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a closed form solution for the sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{^{n}\left(\frac12 \right)} = \frac12 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^{2^2}} + \cdots ?$$

I considered trying a similar approach to the geometric series. By analogy I assign the sum to some variable:

$$S =\sum{^{n}r}$$

By analogy<sup>*</sup>, as the geometric series multiplies by $r$, I decided to raise by $r$

$$S^r = \left( \sum{^{n}r} \right)^r$$

This doesn't distribute nicely however and I'm not exactly sure of a good way to continue (or if there is a good way to continue).

I wasn't able to find anything like this search for "tetration sum" or "generalized geometric series". Maybe I am calling it by the wrong name? If so, sorry if this is a duplicate question.

---

<sup>*</sup> Geometric proof involves exponentiation which is the "third" (after addition and multiplication) operator. It multiplies (the 2nd operator) through by $r$. Thus, tetration is the fourth operator, so I applied the "third" operator (exponentiation) through by $r$.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that this would have a closed form.  One thing you can say is that this is a Liouville number, and thus transcendental.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ah. Ok. Is there a particular reason you say this is unlikely to have a closed form solution? I only ask, because it is unclear to me why people suspect there might be a closed form for $\sum{\frac{1}{k^3}}$ and why it is unlikely this one does...

Comment: We have S = 0.81251525878000000..., which doesn't appear in Google or the OEIS, so it has probably never been studied or given a name.

Comment: The contribute of the $5$th term is about $5\times10^{-19729}$. As the sum of the first $4$ terms is exactly $s_4=0.8125152587890625$ the actual sum is a number which has zillion of zeroes between relatively small groups of nonzero digits. Just like Liouville constant, but with much more zeroes :)